# Understanding Scriptable Objects

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to understand the logic and functionality behind [Scriptable Objects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects). I 've watched the provided video 2 times and I keep getting lost. I tried to follow the code as well but with no luck.

Can someone please explain to me what the Scriptable Objects are and how they work in a few lines?

[EDIT:] *This* [**Video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1YigY3IaE0) as well as the following answers helped me understand Scriptable Objects and even better incorporate them in my own game.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ScriptableObjects` are **just data**... except that they *look like* assets (drag-and-droppable on objects, contained in "Assets", etc).

Consider this code:

```
class ItemShop
{
   ItemList MyAvailableItems;
}
```

Now, for every `ItemShop` instance you create, `MyAvailableItems` contains a unique `ItemList`. Even if every `ItemShop` sells the same set of items, they will each contain their own unique copies. If one instance of the "shared" list is changed, it will NOT propagate back to the original `ItemList` source.

If `ItemList` was a `ScriptableObject`, you could create 100 `ItemShops` and drag the same `ItemList` (from Assets) onto them all. Every instance **REFERENCES** the original (one and only) `ItemList` that you assigned. There is never more than one copy of the `ItemList` in memory.

Additionally, by accessing an entire `ItemList` through a single reference, you can change the items available at the `ItemShop` by swapping in a different reference (one line of code (or a drag and drop, if in editor)).

**Be aware:**

While you are designing your game, you have access to the `Editor` namespace. That allows you to create and/or modify `ScriptableObjects` (at run-time) and then persist those changes back into the actual assets. This lets you run the game, actually visit "tier 3", actually visit the actual item shop, actually change the actual list (at run-time) and then "save" the changes, permanently.

Once built, the `Editor` namespace is lost as well as the ability to persist changes. For that reason, `ScriptableObjects` are **NOT** for saving/loading of run-time-generated data in **built** games; this is a common misunderstanding.

**Edit:**

```
//Data
//(De)serialization is probably your next stop
[System.Serializable] //This will become clear then
class AIBehaviorData //or struct
{
   public float AttackPriority = 0.5f;
   public float DefensePriority = 0.5f;
}

//Implementation
abstract class AIBehavior : ScriptableObject
{
   public bool SomeFlag = false;
   public void Update(AIBehaviorData instanceData) = 0;
}
class TurtleAI : AIBehavior 
{
   public override void Update(AIBehaviorData instanceData)
   {
      //Obviously, no need to assign these over and over...
      //Just example data
      instanceData.AttackPriority = 0.3f;
      instanceData.DefensePriority = 0.7f;
      ... //turtle stuff
   }
}
class AggressiveAI : AIBehavior 
{
   public override void Update(AIBehaviorData instanceData)
   {
      //Obviously, no need to assign these over and over...
      //Just example data
      instanceData.AttackPriority = 0.8f;
      instanceData.DefensePriority = 0.2f;
      ... //aggressive stuff          
   }
}

//Dummy wrapper
class AI_NPC : MonoBehavior
{
   public AIBehaviorData MyInstanceData;

   public AIBehavior MyPersonality; //Public access, visible in inspector, drag-and-drop

   //[HideInInspector]
   //public AIBehavior MyPersonality; //Public access, but not visible in inspector
   //Probably assigned by "AIManager" while creating AI instances

   //private AIBehavior MyPersonality; //Must initialize locally with Awake/Start/OnEnable

   public void Update()
   {
      //Modify my data based on my personality
      if (MyPersonality.SomeFlag)
        MyInstanceData.AttackPriority++;

      //or

      //My personality modifies my data
      if (MyPersonality != null)
        MyPersonality.Update(MyInstanceData);
   }
}

--------------------------------------------------
**Editor namespace**
//Will not build if in same file
using UnityEditor;
//These make your objects really come to life (in the editor at least)
[CustomEditor(typeof(AI_NPC))]
class AI_NPC_Editor : Editor
{
   void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
      serializedObject.Update();
      //This is where the inspector panels are assembled
      AI_NPC inspectedAI = (AI_NPC)target;
      if (inspectedAI.MyPersonality is TurtleAI) //polymorphism
      {
         //Display "turtle" properties (data is in same struct either way)
         ...
         inspectedAI.MyInstanceData.SomeFlag = 
            EditorGuiLayout.Toggle(inspectedAI.MyInstanceData.SomeFlag); //checkbox
      }
      else if (inspectedAI.MyPersonality is AggressiveAI)
      {
         //Display "aggressive" properties (data is in same struct either way)
         ...
      }
      serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
   }
}
```

Now you can drag-and-drop personalities onto AI's. One copy of each is resident in memory at any time, regardless of how many times it is referenced.

---

**Edit:**

The `ScriptableObject` **asset** will be "reset to factory", every time the game loads. If you go to the definition of `ScriptableObject`, you will find that it inherits from `Object` which means you can `Instantiate<>()` (clone) them. Those clones can be overwritten with run-time data, loaded from disk. The class/struct that holds the item-counts for a particular shop can **be** a `ScriptableObject`, that references a specific `ItemList` (a `ScriptableObject`). In that case, a quantity means "there are ten `ItemList[0]`'s available at this shop, right now" (the item list can be swapped out).

If the majority of this answer and `ScriptableObject` makes sense to you, move on to serialization. When you have the save/load framework in place, "where things belong" should become more obvious; you'll probably find that the quantities belong within the `ItemShop` instance, not the `ItemList` (an `ItemShop` "has" an `ItemList` and item-counts, an `ItemList` "has" only items). An `InventoryList` (class/struct or `ScriptableObject`) could reference an `ItemList` (`ScriptableObject`) and contain quantities. Both can be dynamically modified at run-time during save/load.

Based on where they intuitively belong, "should I use a `ScriptableObject` here?" will also be more obvious. If each `ItemShop` has its' own item-count list, there's really nothing to reference; since you HAVE to have multiple instances of the class/struct, the clear benefit of using a `ScriptableObject` instead is diminished. If multiple `ItemShops` can "share inventory", then `ScriptableObject` may be the way to go. You have to consider the size of one class/struct instance, as well as how many identical copies you will be making.

From the tutorial, the "list of 1000 int's" (`Int32`) would occupy approximately 32 KB of memory, so ten copies of that list would occupy approximately 320 KB. Depending on the platform you are developing for, the "excessive memory usage" may not be worth fixing. My PC has about 6,291,456 KB (6 GB) of memory, so 320 KB is 0.005% of my total memory that I don't mind you using. But, if your game can't run on my preferred device (an older Android), I can't buy it.

Some `ItemShops` sharing, and some not, is probably your "worst case", in terms of complexity:

```
[Serializable]
class QuantityData
{
   public ItemList Items;
   ... //Probably a few List<int> representing min/max/current
}
class ScriptableQuantityData : ScriptableObject
{
   public QuantityData MyQuantityData;
}
class ItemShop : MonoBehavior
{
   public QuantityData MyQuantityData = null;
   public ScriptableQuantityData MyScriptableQuantityData = null;

   void DoSomething(int itemID)
   {
      if (MyScriptableQuantityData != null) //Shared inventory
      {
         //MyScriptableQuantityData.MyQuantityData.Items[itemID]
         ...
      }
      else if (MyQuantityData != null) //Private inventory
      {
         //MyQuantityData.Items[itemID]
         ...
      }
      else
      {
         Debug.Log("Error: no QuantityData assigned");
         //throw new exception("Error: no QuantityData assigned");
      }
   }
}
```

Regardless of how you end up layering the data structures, you'll have to provide the (de)serialization mechanism for anything you want to include in save/load. Classes derived from `ScriptableObject` are not `[Serializable]` so you'll need to add enough information for saving so you can reconstruct the objects during load.

It is easy to drag-and-drop `ScriptableObjects` in the Editor. How does an `ItemShop`, loaded from disk, know which of the `QuantityDatas`, also loaded from disk, belongs to **this** shop? Do they have names or unique ID's? You can count on `ItemList[0]` being the same list, time after time, as long as you load/save the same way every time.

Serialization is going to drive most, if not all, of your decision-making from now on.

(I also agree that the tutorial falls short in some critical way, although I can't say precisely how)

Comment: So the ItemList would only have one instance accessed by every Shop. So if in that list there are 5 Potions and one of the shops sells one, does that mean all other shops would show 4 available?

Comment: @Karaflakos, check out the edit.

Comment: Hmm, I like your answer a lot, it is very thorough and it helped me to finally catch the idea of `SO` but I am not yet sure if I need it in my game. As your personal opinion, would you prefer `SO` to create an item _"database"_ or would you use another method?

Comment: @Karaflakos, for a single, constant, game-wide "database", I'd start with `SO`. I wouldn't want to spend more time making an elaborate database editor (not even available in builds) than I do on the game, so I would use a custom editor for my `SO` to add save/load buttons, and then modify the database externally, using Excel. At that point, the only real benefit of `SO` is drag-and-drop since you could provide "global access" to the same dataset using a regular class/struct singleton and still avoid duplicating the data. (It is relatively easy to change your mind later)

Comment: Ok, I have managed to create a `SO` generator that generates weapons. In the generated `Weapon.asset` I have added a `GameObject` which will store the 3D model of the weapon. However I cannot load it into the seen. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a great writeup.

Answer (score 3):

Scriptable objects are data containers to be used in the editor. It is basically a standard data class, except you can make a custom window in the editor to edit that data. It is for making tools to extend Unity.

*Disclaimer: I just started with scriptable objects myself, so take my answer with a grain of salt, and please correct me if I am wrong.*

Comment: When you say custom window in the editor, could you demonstrate an example through a screenshot or video tutorial that is to the point? Is this something like some RPG frameworks that are on the market, for example ORK Framework etc. ?

Comment: I am not asking you to make a video about it only if you know about one that could demonstrate its application in a project.

Comment: I understand that, could you take a look at my first comment on your answer? I've edited it to explain my question better.

Comment: @Karaflakos I am not familiar with ORK framework. But in the video tutorial you linked, the window "ItemInventoryList" at the 50 minute mark was created via their scriptable object. http://youtu.be/9gscwiS3xsU

Comment: Hmm I see! So could we roughly say that Scriptable Objects are a form of a local database? I am guessing it would be a good "substitute" to an XML file or a database which would involve a lot of parsing!

Comment: @Karaflakos I believe so. Comparable to scriptable objects is passing XML data, or having a GameObject you edit in the inspector but never actually use in the Scene.

Comment: @Karaflakos, look for `void OnInspectorGUI()` in my answer; Evorlor is referring to custom Editors, which you can create for all of your objects, not just `ScriptableObjects`. The `OnXXGUI()` methods use the `UnityEditor.SerializableObject` class to request information from an object that may or may not have it. When a member is requested from a class that doesn't contain it, `null` is returned (instead of an exception). That allows you to optimize the editor experience for whatever type of data happens to be getting inspected at this exact moment.

Comment: @Karaflakos, also, if an object with a custom Editor references objects with custom editors, the outer-most editor is able to "borrow" the custom editors of the referenced objects. So, instead of just a one line, drag-and-drop object field, you get the correct inspector for "whatever" is dropped there. Inheritance applies, so if `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` both inherit `BaseClass` which inherits `ScriptableObject`, you can drop either of them on a `BaseClass` object field. `BaseClass` can be `abstract`.

Comment: @Evorlor, I added these as comments here since they are more about editors than `SO` and to help you both (I think it notifies you without having to @ you). I did not intend to hijack your answer. Out of curiousity, if you watched the tutorial to learn this, did you also have to watch it multiple times?

Comment: @Karaflakos, for you both, although `SO` aren't `[Serializable]`, serializing them is rather trivial. I think the serialization tutorial introduces the `BinaryFormatter` but there are other options available to output XML or even plain-text. Once everything serializes correctly, you can swap the formatter for another.

Comment: @Jon your comments are very helpful, thank you. And yes...I had to watch the tutorial twice as well. I was thinking, "hmmm...wouldn't it be awesome if Jon made a super canonical answer here which obsoleted that tutorial.." :-)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the great answers, ScriptableObjects can also contain methods. You could create something like an EventService asset for messaging, passing an instance to your scripts for them to subscribe and use.

You could say that whenever you find yourself considering Singleton patterns, ScriptableObjects as assets usually work just as well (or even better).